# Fetching data from XML document into SQL table, empty table when using OPENROWSET for retrieving attribute from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to insert attributes from a XML file into a SQL table. I have roamed Stackoverflow to find a solution but nothing I tried seems to work.

I have tried with and without defining and using the namespace and also all kind of different node-path combinations for navigating through the XML.

Here is a part of the Xml which I would like to retrieve the attributes from:

```
``<export xmlns="http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export" xmlns:at="http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export GoodsNomenclature.xsd ">
  <id>e37c6378-892a-4c25-b3fe-d0f3fcdf5a29</id>
  <exportType>GoodsNomenclatureObject</exportType>
  <parameters />
  <items>
    <goodsNomenclature at:goodsNomenclatureCode="0101109090" at:dateEnd="2011-06-30" at:national="0" at:productLineSuffix="80" at:SID="74778" at:dateStart="2002-01-01" at:statisticalIndicator="0" at:changeType="U">
      <goodsNomenclatureIndent at:national="0" at:quantityIndents="03" at:SID="74084" at:dateStart="2002-01-01" />
      <goodsNomenclatureDescriptionPeriod at:national="0" at:SID="92833" at:dateStart="2002-01-01">
        <goodsNomenclatureDescription at:description="andere" at:languageId="NL" at:national="0" />
        <goodsNomenclatureDescription at:description="Other" at:languageId="EN" at:national="0" />
      </goodsNomenclatureDescriptionPeriod>
    </goodsNomenclature>
  </items>
</export>``
```

This is the last code which I tried:

```
INSERT INTO TblGoodsNomenclature(XMLData, CreatedDate)
SELECT Convert(Xml, BulkColumn) as BulkColumn, GETDATE()
FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk '\\shareapp\c$\temp\GoodsNomenclature.xml', Single_Blob) as x;

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XmlData FROM TblGoodsNomenclature

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML, '<export xmlns="http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export" xmlns:at="http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export"/>'

INSERT INTO NomenclatureCodes (NomenclatureCode, Description, DescriptionLanguage)
SELECT NomenclatureCode, Description, DescriptionLanguage
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/items/goodsNomenclature/goodsNomenclatureDescriptionPeriod/goodsNomenclatureDescription/at:node')
    WITH 
    (
        NomenclatureCode INT '@at:goodsNomenclatureCode',
        Description [varchar](100) '@at:description',
        DescriptionLanguage [varchar](5) '@at:languageID'

    )
```

The result which I am getting now is just an empty table, no error messages. What I would like to have is the 'goodsNomeclatureCode', the 'description' and the 'languageID' in a table.

Comment: Please don't put the data in the comments. Comments can't be formatted. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55934343/edit) your question and include the information there. That XML in the above comment isn't valid XML either; perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: Also, personally, i would use XQUERY rather than `OPENXML` to get data from XML in SQL Server. The former doesn't rely on `sp_xml_preparedocument `.

Comment: `OPENXML` and friends are the SQL Server 2000 way of doing things. The method-based approach of 2005+ is much better and doesn't require mucking about with handles. To toss namespaces into that mix, use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`; the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces#using-with-xmlnamespaces-with-the-xml-data-type-methods) have some examples.

Comment: @Larnu, what do you mean with the XML not being valid?

Comment: The XML comment has gone now (and you haven't added it to your question) so I can't tell you an exact reason any more, but I recall it being incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, first post so I had to get used to the formatting. I put the XML back in, maybe you can tell me if it's correctly formatted? @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're far better off using XQUERY here. As you have multiple namespaces as well we need to declare them too. This gives you the following query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export',
                    'http://www.arcticgroup.se/tariff/arctictariff/export' AS [at])
SELECT GN.XMLData,
       EI.gN.value('@at:goodsNomenclatureCode[1]','varchar(15)') AS goodsNomenclatureCode
FROM dbo.TblGoodsNomenclature GN
     CROSS APPLY GN.XMLData.nodes('export/items/goodsNomenclature') EI(gN);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74cb73dd7ba9f00e51081d00c5a2784c)

Comment: You're welcome @britta. Please do mark the answer as the solution if so, then future readers know that the answer was helpful. You also get reputation for marking an answer as a solution; which is invaluable for new users to get those initial privileges.